Why is the spin degree of freedom associated with angular momentum?
Suppose we accept the suggestion of Uhlenbeck and Goudsmit that the electron has a spin degree of freedom which can take two values.
But why should it be linked to the angular momentum?

I believe it could be because that the Lie algebra of spin degree of freedom has a resounding resemblance with the QM operators of angular momentum.

When you rotate a system or the coördinate system, it behaves exactly the same as orbital angular momentum, and you can also exchange angular momentum between orbital and spin parts with exact conservation between them. Their interaction with a magnetic field is also essentially equivalent, just with a difference of a factor of 2 that is directly predicted by Dirac's equation (and mildly modified by QED corrections). As such, it satisfies too many defining characteristics of angular momentum to be denied being one.

The question is unclear to me.

I highly suggest a reading of the following lecture notes: https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/noahmiller/files/representation-theory-quantum.pdf especially (but not only) chapter 15

What do you mean by ‘ Suppose we accept the suggestion of Uhlenbeck and Goudsmit that the electron has a spin degree of freedom which can take two values.’?

@my2cts   I mean simply a variable which can take two discrete values, like a bit in a computer. It is then unclear why this variable should be linked to angular momentum.

Is there anyone who does not accept the suggestion of Uhlenbeck and Goudsmit?

Because it is angular momentum. More correctly, it's an angular momentum operator. Spin operators follow the conmutation relation
$$[S_i,S_j]=i\hbar\varepsilon_{ijk}S_k.$$
Any three operators $S_i$ that follow these relations are angular operator momentum operators by definition, essentially. In particular, the total angular momentum is $\vec{J}=\vec{L}+\vec{S}$. It has an orbital component and an intrinsic angular momentum (spin) component. The theory of how the two operators couple to yield the total angular momentum eigenvalues is vital to an understanding of atomic and nuclear physics (and generally, any system that has multiple non-scalar particles in "orbit"). If spin is not an angular momentum, how do you explain the fact that the $^1$H nucleus has angular momentum, when in the fundamental state it's an $S$ wave configuration ($l=0$)?
Experimentally, you can refer to the well known Stern-Gerlach experiment. Silver atoms have an outer shell $5s^1$, all the other electrons "cancel out" and this yields it an overall angular momentum of $\pm \hbar/2$ associated to the spin of this electron. This angular momentum in turn grants it a magnetic dipole moment $\mu$ that makes the atom behave like any magnetic dipole moment would under a magnetic field, with the caveat that the magnetic moment is also quantized. A particle or object with magnetic moment suffers a torque, a force under a magnetic field, and this causes it to move. This is observed in the Stern-Gerlach experiment. A classical electron orbiting around a nucleus (essentially, a circular current, that has angular momentum) is known to grant a magnetic dipole moment. This fact immediately connects spin with angular momentun.
There are many more reasons. Spin behaves like angular momentum in essentially every way, denying it would limit understanding out of "classical spite".

Spin is linked to angular momentum because spin is linked to symmetry under rotations.
When a Lagrangian has symmetry under rotations, there is a conserved quantity associated with that symmetry. We call that conserved quantity by the name angular momentum.
If, in a given case, there is no coupling between the spin and the orbital angular momentum, then each is conserved separately. In this situation you could, if you like, give some other name to the conserved quantity associated with spin. There is nothing especially wrong with such a naming, but you would also notice that the spin operator has the same commutation relations (among its three components) as orbital angular momentum operator so you would be very temped to call it 'intrinsic angular momentum' or something like that. A similar argument applies in classical physics where you would notice that spin behaves like the contribution to total angular momentum owing to the motion of a body or system about its own centre of mass.
But the real clincher is that there are, in the physical world, plenty of examples of interactions between spin and orbital motion, where the Lagrangian still has an overall rotational symmetry. In that case the conserved quantity is not $\bf S$ or $\bf L$ but
$$
{\bf J} \equiv {\bf S} + {\bf L} 
$$
In this situation the connection between spin and angular momentum is owing to the dynamics. So it is a connection brought about by physics as opposed to pure mathematics. However the pure mathematics is still relevant, because only a quantity which is already, by its own nature, angular-momentum-like could be added to the orbital angular momentum so as to get a conserved quantity.

I will give a more mathematical take on the answer, mainly taken from the following lecture notes: https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/noahmiller/files/representation-theory-quantum.pdf
It boils down to the intimate connection between $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$: long story short $SO(3)$ is the spin 1 representation of $SU(2)$. To see this consider a vector in 3d space and write the isomorphism:
$$
(x,y,z)\leftrightarrow x\sigma_x+y\sigma_y + z\sigma_z=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
z & x-iy\\
x+iy & -z
\end{array}
\right)=\Sigma
$$
Then we can define a group homomorphism
$$
\pi:SU(2)\rightarrow SO(3)
$$
defined by conjugation of the matrix $\Sigma$ by g.
For example we could have
$$
\pi\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
e^{i\theta} & 0\\
0 & e^{-i\theta}
\end{array}
\right)\vec x = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
e^{i\theta} & 0\\
0 & e^{-i\theta}
\end{array}
\right)\Sigma\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
e^{-i\theta} & 0\\
0 & e^{i\theta}
\end{array}
\right)
$$
In this way we can explicitly find which $SO(3)$ matrix any $SU(2)$ matrix maps to. But then since it it possible to classify all $SU(2)$ irreps you see that $SO(3)$ is just the spin one representation of $SU(2)$. This is the connection between spin and angular momentum.
